# Save GET URI while doing POST in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I need to save GET URI to use it later after POSTing form in Flask. The problem is, that it is overwritten when doing POST. Here is the code (schematically):

```py
@app.route('/test', methods=['get', 'post'])
def test_view():
    url_query = request.url.replace(request.base_url,'/')

    form = Form()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
      # at this point url_query is already overriten with '/'
      yadayada(url_query)
```

So, for example, if user requests https://host/test?kekeke=nenene
I expecting that the string "/test?kekeke=nenene" would be passed to yadayada(), but at practice it would be overwritten by '/'. How to solve that properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `Form` action to include the query parameters:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('test_view', **request.args) }}">
```

where the [`request.args` object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.args) gives you access to the query parameters, and the [`url_for()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for) generates a new URL with every key-value pair from `request.args` as query parameters.

Now when the form is POSTed the exact same query parameters are sent along as where used for the original GET request that rendered the form.

Comment: Can't say I like the solution, but it works as needed. Thanks a lot!